# Pandas dataframe insert into SQL Server taking too long with execute and executemany

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pyodbc, execute

I have a pandas dataframe with 27 columns and ~45k rows that I need to insert into a SQL Server table.

I am currently using with the below code and it takes 90 mins to insert:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};\
                   Server=@servername;\
                   Database=dbtest;\
                   Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()  #Create cursor



 for index, row in t6.iterrows():

    cursor.execute("insert into dbtest.dbo.test( col1, col2, col3, col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,,col27)\
                                                        values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                                                        row['col1'],row['col2'], row['col3'],,row['col27'])
```

I have also tried to load using executemany and that takes even longer to complete, at nearly 120mins.

I am really looking for a faster load time since I need to run this daily.

Comment: have you tried `pandas.to_sql` ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html )? and pass `'append'` to the `if_exists` parameter?

Comment: [Generally, iterrows should only be used in very, very specific cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/1422451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set fast_executemany in pyodbc itself for versions>=4.0.19. It is off by default.

```py
import pyodbc

server_name = 'localhost'
database_name = 'AdventureWorks2019'
table_name = 'MyTable'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{'+driver+'}', server=server_name, database=database_name, trusted_connection='yes') 

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.fast_executemany = True   # reduce number of calls to server on inserts

# form SQL statement
columns = ", ".join(df.columns)

values = '('+', '.join(['?']*len(df.columns))+')'
      
statement = "INSERT INTO "+table_name+" ("+columns+") VALUES "+values

# extract values from DataFrame into list of tuples
insert = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]

cursor.executemany(statement, insert)
```

Or if you prefer sqlalchemy and dataframes directly.

```py
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@'+server_name+'/'+database_name+'?trusted_connection=yes&driver='+driver, fast_executemany=True)

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

See fast_executemany in this link.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API

Answer (score 1):

I have worked through this in the past, and this was the fastest that I could get it to work using `sqlalchemy`.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = (sa.create_engine(f'mssql://@{server}/{database}
          ?trusted_connection=yes&driver={driver_name}', fast_executemany=True)) #windows authentication
df.to_sql('Daily_Report', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

If the engine is not working for you, then you may have a different setup so please see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html

You should be able to create the variables needed above, but here is how I get the `driver`:

```
driver_name = ''
driver_names = [x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.endswith(' for SQL Server')]
if driver_names:
    driver_name = driver_names[-1] #You may need to change the [-1] if wrong driver to [-2] or a different option in the driver_names list.
if driver_name:
    conn_str = f'''DRIVER={driver_name};SERVER='''
else:
    print('(No suitable driver found. Cannot connect.)')
```

Comment: The above throws out an error 'TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uri''. I tried creating the engine in a separate variable but that doesn't work either..

Comment: @user10 I'm sorry, I assumed `dask` and `pandas` had the same parameters for the `to_sql` function. I'll update my answer with the `pandas` way.

Comment: So, I have a daily report that I use `dask` with on 20 million rows and it takes about an hour, using alll of the same methods but passing `con` for `pandas` instead of `uri` for `dask`. I think `to_sql` should have similar performance on `dask` and `pandas`, so hoefully the above code now works for you and it is quick given a small dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the method 'multi' built in pandas to_sql.

```
df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, method='multi')
```

The multi method allows you to 'Pass multiple values in a single INSERT clause.' per documentation.
I found it to be pretty efficient.